How to design for 3,000 pixel mobile screens
I'm kinda confused. We use pixels for pretty much everything, from font size to breakpoints. I recently designed a website which changed to mobile landscape view at 770px but when viewing on my mobile I always get the tablet size as my mobile is 960px wide in landscape. This got me thinking... How are we supposed to design for mobiles that are over 3000px wide but still standard size in inches? Surely everything would look tiny. Would it not make more sense to design in millimeters? Or am I totally misunderstanding it all?

I think there is some confusion:
There are 2 width types:
let's say: 375px x 600px (W/H) MOBILE
So if you take a screenshot then the size you would see will be like 1080px x 1920px. (Its for Images and Videos and other media types)
But, if you will browse websites in Apps or Browsers the size that will still be used will be: 375x600.
Hope this answers your question. Thank you.

Oh that's interesting. Makes a lot of sense. Thankyou.

What device have you seen that is 3000px wide? Typically, the standard size of a mobile device is 320-480px. The reason pixels are used as opposed to another standard unit of measurement is because they are the smallest unit for digital images and screens.

I just googled highest resolution phones. Check the link below.
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/highest-resolution-phone-best-ppi-smartphones-2024-moto-smartphones-qyyhc/
